# How to prevent a dependency usage in a particular scope for a Maven project?

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

There is a multimodule Maven project depending on a "library ABC".

I would like to **prevent usage of this library** in the project from now on.
It could possibly be used by other dependencies, and that is not a problem --
the goal is ensure the project itself does not depend on it in scopes "compile" and "test".

From the practical perspective, developers should not be able to accidentally import classes from ABC to the project classes. Consider that there are multiple modules, and it is natural that some new dependencies could be added. Still they should not implicitly make the library ABC be available in the project code.

**How to configure the build to forbid explicit usage of a particular dependency?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) to force developers to specify direct dependencies and [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) to ban certain dependencies
2. [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) to ban certain imports in java code.